# Error getting data from mysql using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to get data from mysql database using ajax. I adapted my old ajax code that works OK in different project, but It does not work here.

I use javascript function as bellow:

```
var text1 = document.getElementById('ST0_nazwaMenu');
var combo1 = document.getElementById('S0_dzienMenu');
var combo2 = document.getElementById('S0_posilekMenu');

function zaladujSzczegoly() {
        if (text1.value.trim() != "" && combo1.value.trim() != "" && combo2.value.trim() != "") {

                var nazwaMenu = text1.value.trim();
                var dzienMenu = combo1.value.trim();
                var posilekMenu = combo2.value.trim();

                $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "test.php",
                        data: {"jadlospis": nazwaMenu.val(), "dzien": combo1.val(), "posilek": combo2.val()},
                }).done(function( data ) {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                });


                alert(text1.value);

        }
}

text1.addEventListener('change', zaladujSzczegoly, false);
combo1.addEventListener('change', zaladujSzczegoly, false);
combo2.addEventListener('change', zaladujSzczegoly, false);
```

The test.php file is just for testing and it looks like this:

```
<?php

include 'db_connection.php';
include 'functions.php';


error_log("-->test.php:"."\n", 3, "/var/www/html/jadlospis/errors.log");

if (isset($_POST['jadlospis'],$_POST['dzien'],$_POST['posilek'])){

        error_log($_POST['jadlospis']."\n", 3, "/var/www/html/jadlospis/errors.log");

        $SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Konta FROM users WHERE jadlospis='".$_POST['jadlospis']."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$SQL ) or die(mysqli_error($this->dblink));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
                $T_Count=$row['Konta'];
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo $result;
}

?>
```

After changing form controls the function is called and then, I got an error message in browser console saying: **TypeError: nazwaMenu.val is not a function**

Any hints on what the problem might be, please?

Comment: You already got the value when you did `nazwaMenu = text1.value.trim();` you don't need to call `val()`.

Comment: `combo1.val()` should be `combo1.value`. `val()` is a jQuery method, but `combo1` is a DOM element.

Comment: You're confusing yourself by mixing DOM methods like `getElementById` with jQuery methods like `$("#S0_dzienMenu")`. Pick one or the other and use them consistently.

Answer (score 2):

You have already fetched the value of `text1` into variable `nazwaMenu` so you do not need to call `nazwaMenu.val()`
You can use `text1.value.trim()` or `$("#ST0_nazwaMenu").val().trim()` or just the varibale containing value `nazwaMenu`

because `.val()` can not be called on value or DOM, to usr `.val()` object needs to be of JQuery Object

replace your this line

```
data: {"jadlospis": nazwaMenu.val(), "dzien": combo1.val(), "posilek": combo2.val()},
```

with

```
data: {"jadlospis": nazwaMenu, "dzien": dzienMenu , "posilek": posilekMenu }
```

and you should be fine~

Comment: You are right, but I think you won't need the , at the end. As data is the last one.

Comment: it doesn't make difference  with the OP's problem though. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yeah right. The main problem is val(). Yours the correct! Good job

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
data: {"jadlospis": nazwaMenu, "dzien": combo1, "posilek": combo2}
```

You won't need a `,` at the end, as it is the last value.

**Edit:** Please see @Irony Stack solution, `val()` is not needed anymore.